# SQL Server: Concat stopping partway through

Tags: sql, sql-server, types, concatenation, sql-server-2017

I'm building some dynamic SQL generators for frequently duplicated scalar functions, and I'm running into an issue with `CONCAT`: namely, it stops partway through the operation, and returns an incomplete (truncated) string value.

(I've tried with + operators, and `CONCAT` function calls, same results either way.)

I put a comment on the bottom line, showing exactly where it truncates the return value.

Is this a data type discrepancy?
I tried manually casting some of the strings to `NVARCHAR ( 4000 )`, but it didn't change anything.
I also tried using `NVARCHAR ( MAX )`, but again it made no difference to the result.

In this example, `@FunctionName` and `@DescriptivePKColumnName` are both `NVARCHAR ( 48 )` and are not null or empty.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR ( 4000 ) =
    IIF ( EXISTS ( SELECT 1    /* CREATE vs ALTER, does the function already exist? */
                   FROM   [sys].[objects]
                   WHERE  [object_id] = OBJECT_ID ( N'[dbo].[' + @FunctionName + N']' ) ) ,
N'ALTER' , N'CREATE' ) + N' FUNCTION [dbo].[' + @FunctionName + N']    /* so far so good */
(
    @' + @DescriptivePKColumnName + N'Param TINYINT NOT NULL    /* final + gets hung up */
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR ( 48 )
WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION ,
     SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN ATOMIC WITH ( TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT     ,
                       LANGUAGE                    = N''English'' )
    RETURN' ;     /* Concat ends prematurely with '= N''Engli' */
```

Here's a screenshot of the immediate window:
[image]

Comment: Is the generated string bigger than 4000 ?

Comment: @LukStorms Nope, should be around 500-700 characters when I typed it out manually. And as of right now, it doesn't even make it past 240 chars before stopping.

Comment: What does SELECT LEN(@SQL) show? Or are you printing it to the output window?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean I added a screenshot of the immediate window. When I copy/paste that into MSWord, it says 239 characters. (it includes some extra tab characters which I removed from the snippet example, to make it easier to read.)

Comment: That is the sql showing in Visual Studio? Have you tried SSMS? I can't repro in SSMS with a SQL Server 2017 database.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean SSMS is where I've been debugging. That immediate window screenshot is SSMS 2017. I haven't tried in Visual Studio ... (Also, I hacked SSMS to enable the dark color theme, if that's confusing you.) If you can't repro, that's concerning. I just upgraded SSMS to the latest version a couple days ago, I wouldn't think it would be broken so subtly, if everything else works just fine? Super weird ...

Comment: I think it is a display only issue. If you EXEC the sql, does it work? Maybe related: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2795/prevent-truncation-of-dynamically-generated-results-in-sql-server-management-studio/

Comment: I ran into similar issues when creating large blobs of SQL; I ended up having to PRINT multiple times to avoid the shortcomings of the PRINT statement.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean OK interesting. So here's the deal, EXEC doesn't work, because by the time it gets to that point, a bunch more concats have occurred, and `@SQL` becomes an empty string at some point. I figured this earlier spot would be the first place to investigate, but I guess I need to look for bugs (*ahem* null values being concatenated?) farther down in the code. Thanks for letting me know this isn't unheard of.

Comment: OK, I can confirm this behavior is an issue with the immediate window. The variable will PRINT the entire contents, but the immediate window truncates the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the debug windows in SSMS (immediate, watch, etc.)
It seems that the debug windows have a character limit, and they truncate longer strings.

If you `PRINT @SQL` you should see the entire concatenated string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @FunctionName NVARCHAR(255) = 'dbo.test'
DECLARE @DescriptivePKColumnName  NVARCHAR(255) = 'Column1'

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1    
    FROM [sys].[objects]
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@FunctionName)
)
BEGIN
    set @SQL = 'ALTER'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    set @SQL = 'CREATE'
END

SET @SQL += ' FUNCTION ' + @FunctionName + '(@' + @DescriptivePKColumnName +'Param  TINYINT)
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(48)
WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION , SCHEMABINDING
AS 
BEGIN ATOMIC WITH (TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT,LANGUAGE = N''English'' )
    RETURN
END'
```